# Is there any fast tool which performs constant substitution without stripping out comments in JavaScript source code?

Tags: node.js, compilation, javascript

For example, setting `MYCONST = true` would lead to the transformation of

```
 if (MYCONST) {
     console.log('MYCONST IS TRUE!'); // print important message
 }
```

to

```
 if (true) {
     console.log('MYCONST IS TRUE!'); // print important message
 }
```

This tool ideally has a fast node.js accessible API.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You shouldn't be generating JavaScript code changes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in a broader sense? I get the feeling you're overlooking simpler options.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it with `if (true)`? Seems like it would make a lot more sense to entirely remove the `if` and replace it with just the `console.log` call.

Comment: I'm trying to keep line numbers intact while performing constant substitution needed for building a script which is already designed with constants in mind.

Comment: @luxun Why? You might keep line numbers in tact but your code will no longer make sense.

Comment: @luxun You've mentioned not stripping *comments* several times but you seem to be referring to the string literals. Just to clarify, when you say *comment* you mean the string literal `'MYCONST IS TRUE!'` not the comment `// print important message`, correct?

Comment: No. I'm referring to `// print important message`, although string literals should also be preserved.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer for debugging

Comment: Luxun assert values, don't hard change your code throughout your scripts for that sake... if that's what you want it for, @Sripathi's answer below is best, cause then you can flip it like a light switch from one spot, and not hard wire your code so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google's closure compiler does, among other things, inlining of constants when annotated as such, leaving string content [untouched](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html) but I am not sure if it's a viable option for you.

Comment: I need to leave *comments* untouched.

Comment: comments will be left untouched if you instruct the tool to do so (I think there is a CLI option to keep all comments, otherwise just annotating them with `@preserve` or `@license`).

Comment: okay. closure is a bit slow, but if nobody has a faster solution, this works :)

Comment: I can't find the CLI option. I need to preserve *all* comments.

Comment: I'll accept this as the bounty due to time, but could you please update your question telling me how to do this exactly?

Comment: you are right that there is no CLI option, I'll update the answer with a note about `@preserve`. I can reuse your bounty to put up a question on how to run a single closure-compiler pass, if you want

Answer (score 3):

A better way to achieve what you want -

Settings.js

```
 settings = {
   MYCONST = true
 };
```

MainCode.js

```
 if (settings.MYCONST) {
     console.log('MYCONST IS TRUE!'); // print important message
 }
```

This way, you make a change to one single file.

Comment: If you are downvoting this, please leave a comment explaining why you are doing so. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how does this answer his question? It appears you are providing an alternative to performing js-file-changing const subtitution. Am I wrong in believing this?

Comment: +1 ... while it is not exactly what the question was asking for, he did state in a comment that it was for debugging... in which case your answer is vastly preferable to find/replacing constants to switch their values.

Answer (score 1):

Patch a beautifier, for example

- Get the JS Beautifier https://raw.github.com/einars/js-beautify/master/beautify.js written in JS.
- Replace the last line of `function print_token()` by something like

  output.push(token_text=="MYCONST"?"true":token_text);
- Call `js_beautify(your_code)` from within nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) build system supports a [replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) that could be used to achieve this.

Comment: except this would not just replace the token, would it? it would make the `console.log('true IS TRUE')` which is not what I want.

Comment: Ah, that is true.  Perhaps you could choose some convention such as _TOKEN_MYCONST for identifiers that will be replaced, or just define your constants as actual variables.

Comment: no... You would need to search for comment patterns and skip what is inside. Should be pretty ready to hack something together in grep with reg ex

Comment: Nooooo don't, this would still hurt if the same name existed in a different scope. You need an ECMAScript parser for that, not regexes.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Whoops. Gotta read title first. Ignore me.

[Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/overview.html) has such a feature:

You can combine the [@define](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html#tag-define) tag in your code with the `--define` parameter to change variables at "compile" time.

The closure compiler will also remove your if-statement, which is probably what you want.

Simply write your code like this:

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var MYCONST = false; // default value is necessary here

if (MYCONST) {
    console.log('MYCONST IS TRUE!'); // print important message
}
```

And call the compiler with the parameter:

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --define=MYCONST=true --js pathto/file.js
```

Regarding you API request: Closure Compiler has a [JSON API](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial1.html).