# How to run a single pass with closure compiler?

Tags: java, javascript, compilation, google-closure-compiler

Google's Closure Compiler jar executable has a neat `--print_pass_graph` option that shows what passes are being executed given a set of options to the compiler.

What I am interested in knowing is: how to run a single pass?

For example, how to run the single `processDefines` step (possibly with dependencies), while avoiding `denormalize` or `operaCompoundAssignFix` ?

(follow up question to [Is there any fast tool which performs constant substitution without stripping out comments in JavaScript source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582798/is-there-any-fast-tool-which-performs-constant-substitution-without-stripping-ou/8668281#8668281) but interesting by itself)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing this but one way is to replace the DefaultPassConfig with a custom one that only runs the pass you want, the Compiler class's setPassConfig allow this:
    http://www.google.com/codesearch#l5BkQmivP-Y/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/Compiler.java&q=DefaultPassConfig%20package:http://closure-compiler%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=692